# How to type pretty when using LINQ in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

I have a little problem with Visual Studio 2015 when using `LINQ`.

Example:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Age { get; set; }

    public string Sex { get; set; }
}

var result = form v in DB.test
             select new TestModel
             {
                 Name = "Hello" <----
             };
```

When I want to enter next property in TextModel,
I press "," and press "Enter" to next line.

But , It doesn't show any `intellisense tooltips` about `TestModel`'s property.

I must enter something or whitespace to let it show `intellisense tooltips` that I can easy to select property.

but this will make code look bad,I must format code when I complete this code.

Have any way can show `Intellisense tooltips` when I 'm at new line ,no need type something?

1.When at new line , must type something like whitespace, then show `intellisense tooltips`...
[image]

2.When I keep typing property , It will be like this (because I must type whitespace to show Intellisense tooltips`...I must fomat code when I finished.
[image]

So, Have any way to call `Intellisense tooltips` when I at new line and not to type something?

Comment: Did you try pressing Ctrl+Space?

Comment: @SLaks Yeah, but it's seems the same

Comment: well then enter backspace and then space

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani ,I do this sometime ... ):.